# I want to execute few selected test cases from my class of multiple test cases using Junit3 with ease

Tags: selenium-rc, junit3

As my 1-2 test cases are failing from bunch of test cases and also finding difficult to execute whole test suite again for these two, is there any method without adding comment to the others or copying these two methods in different suite.

Thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the tests you don't want to run, add the `@Ignore` annotation. For example:

```
@Ignore
@Test
public void testLala() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: i m not able to run this as i am using Junit3 instead of Junit4

Comment: You can rename the tests you don't want to run to not begin with 'test'

Comment: The above @Ignore is not working at my side i am using  `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main("SuiteCB");`